# RMI over http/s using Jboss 7.1.1

Tags: java, jboss, rmi, jboss7.x

We are upgrading from JBoss 4 to JBoss 7.1.1. Our existing client communicates with the server via RMI over http/s. We will be soon using REST/SOAP for our communication. But for the time being is there a way (work-around) to invoke RMI calls over http/s using JBoss 7.1.1.

Comment: @EJP Jboss 7.1.1 has stopped supporting rmi over http. Though they have plans to support it again in 7.2 (unreleased)

Comment: Blimey. Remind me to keep not using JBoss :-)

Comment: @Nik, so why just no wait for 7.2? :-)